# SQLite Database Android - Joining Tables

Tags: android, jquery, mysql, database, sqlite

> Hi guys, i am new on working for joining tables on my android application. I have my 3 tables named EMPLOYEES, PASSWALL and NOTEPAD. I want to access the other tables using a foreign key on my EMPLOYEES table. Do you get my point?
>
> I need a QUERY for that and how to SELECT it and how to access datas on other tables.
>
> So how is the approach for that? thanks appreciate your suggestions.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(EMPID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LI_USERNAME TEXT UNIQUE, LI_PASSWORD TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PASSWALL(PWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PW_DESC TEXT UNIQUE, PW_PASS TEXT, PW_NOTE TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE NOTEPAD(NPID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NP_TITLE TEXT UNIQUE, NP_BODY TEXT, NP_DATE TEXT);");
```

Comment: Can we have your table structure.....

Answer (score -1):

```
Select E.*,P.* from EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN PASSWALL P ON E.foreign key = P.id;
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: I am just joined two tables by using foreign key and nothing wrong in this. but some one marked this minus.